# Execute Long running php scripts via cron jobs

Tags: php, cron

I have a php script that updates a database. It takes round 5 minutes to complete. I want to set it to run automatically via cron job on cpanel but it don't execute via cron job.

Is there any time execution limit on cron jobs or is there any other effective way to automate this process on server?

Answer (score 0):

`set_time_limit()` might help you

[documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

you can use supervisor to keep command line tasks running

Comment: Thanks for the help! Do you have any link to supervisor documentation please?

Comment: @MrNano http://supervisord.org/ searching for your specific os tutorial (CentOs for example) would be an easier solution then the official document in my opinion